# simple c error makes pointer from integer without a cast

Tags: c, pointers

I've undertaken learning c with the aid of the k & r book. Pretty exciting but I've run into trouble early on and I'm not sure how to fix the problem.

I'm trying out some really simple sample code and I'm getting the following error. I don't understand why because the code is straight out of the book.

```
main.c:11: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘sprintf’ makes pointer from integer without a cast


#include <stdio.h>

/* copy input to output; 1st version */
main() {
    int i;
    int power(int base, int n);

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        sprintf("%d %d %d\n", i ,power(2, i), power(-3, i));
        return 0;
    }



}

int power(int base, int n) {
    int i;
    int p;

    p = 1;

    for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
        p = p * base;
    return p;

}
```

I'd appreciate a nudge to get me going  on my way again.

Comment: Why is there a `return` inside your `for` loop?

Comment: The code is exact "as is" from the book. Is the return a problem?

Comment: I'm going to have to bring out my copy of K&R, because that is some FUNKY code.

Comment: @dubbeat: that is definitely not "as is" from the book. You have added a set of braces around the `printf` and `return` statements. Yes, you have also mistyped `printf` into `sprintf`.

Comment: ahhhh...... o.k i'm embarressed

Comment: We all make mistakes, sometimes in public. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sprintf` is for creating a string based on some formatting. It looks like you want output, so you want to use `printf`.

Also, `return 0;` should not be be enclosed in your `for` loop. It would result in termination of the program after one iteration.

Answer (score 3):

From `man sprintf`:
       int sprintf(char *str, const char *format, ...);

The first argument to sprintf is the string you have allocated.

If you want to print to the standard output (usually the terminal in which you run the program), use `printf` instead.

Answer (score 1):

for everybody who dont knows abouwt the loop with return
there is a differance between:

```
for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
    p = p * base;    //inside
return p;            //outside because no brackets {}
```

and:

```
for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i){
    p = p * base;    //inside
    return p;}       //inside because brackets {}
```

if you don't use brackets in a loop or if statement, only the direct next line will be executed. this return is outside the loop

Answer (score 0):

`sprintf()` expects a string as first and second arguments.

The first one designates the string where you want to store the result and the second one is the format string.

You may want to use `printf()` instead of `sprintf()`.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of `sprintf()` is the buffer you are supposed to be printing to.  The second is the format string.

(Also consider using `snprintf()` -- it's much easier to write safe code that doesn't overrun the buffer.)

Answer (score 0):

this is just a compiler *warning*, but the process should have been completed succesfully if you didnt get any error messages...
you could get around the warning by adding an explicit cast to line 11..
check for ["type casting c"](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&biw=1298&bih=976&q=type+casting+c&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=) on google ;)

Comment: Warning are always indicators of poor coding. In this case, it reveals a bug, where the wrong function is used or where an argument is missing.

Comment: true, but my point was that the subject says it's an error, while it is not.